# Pipenv: Underlying buffer has been detached

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv

I want to install a local package using Pipenv. It works fine with Python 3.6, but unfortunately I have to use a higher version (due to some libraries I intend to install later). I tried 3.8 and 3.9 and get the following error:

```bash
pipenv install -e . --python 3.9
```

fails with

```bash
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
dencies
    results, ireq = self.resolve_reqs(download_dir, ireq, wheel_cache)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\piptools\repositories\pypi.py", line 297, in resolve_reqs
    results = resolver._resolve_one(reqset, ireq)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\resolve.py", line 263, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\resolve.py", line 211, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 275, in prepare_linked_requirement
    unpack_url(
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\download.py", line 831, in unpack_url
    unpack_http_url(
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\download.py", line 670, in unpack_http_url
    from_path, content_type = _download_http_url(link,
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\download.py", line 898, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes, progress_bar)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\download.py", line 598, in _download_url
    progress_indicator = DownloadProgressProvider(progress_bar,
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\utils\ui.py", line 282, in DownloadProgressProvider
    return BAR_TYPES[progress_bar][0](max=max).iter
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\utils\ui.py", line 178, in __init__
    super(WindowsMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\utils\ui.py", line 88, in __init__
    super(InterruptibleMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\utils\ui.py", line 138, in __init__
    super(DownloadProgressMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_vendor\progress\helpers.py", line 58, in __init__
    if self.file and self.file.isatty() and self.hide_cursor:
ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached
```

Most surprisingly, the error message references `c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36` even though it names the correct location of the Python when setting up the environment:

```bash
Using C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe (3.9.13) to create virtualenv…
```

Setup in `setup.py` file:

```py
setup(name=name,
      version=_version['__version__'],
      long_description=long_description,
      long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
      python_requires=">=3.6",
      packages=find_packages(),
      install_requires=[
          'requests>=2.26.0',
          'shapely>=1.6.4',
          'numpy>=1.17.0',
          'xarray>=0.12.3',
          'pandas>0.20.0',
          'deprecated>=1.2.12'
      ],
)
```

Comment: I "solved" this by uninstalling everything (pipenv, pip, all Python versions) and freshly installed Python 3.9 and pip. After that it worked.